# Short story where a man discovers he's living in a fake world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I may be conflating two separate short science-fiction stories here, so please bear with me. I definitely read this more than 10 years ago and it's likely to be older than that (60's, 70's?)

---

A man wakes up one day to discover that the world is subtly different. His wife acts strangely and there's a weird "groundhog day" vibe.

- He discovers that his house is actually made entirely of painted metal, including things that should be wood (a boat that he made by hand, for example).
- He comments that in the real world, it's the fact that stuff *doesn't* work properly that shows you that you're living in reality (a wobbly doorhandle may have been mentioned?)
- He's constantly beset by advertising; brands of washing powder, political messages, etc. and people keep asking him what he thought about them.
- At one point, the advertisers start getting very aggressive, literally invading his house to dirty his clothes and driving around with megaphones to shout slurs about their political competitors.
- He finally breaks out of the town (with the assistance of his secretary?) and they discover that they're...

> ...actually robots living in a simulated town used by advertisers to test slogans, etc.

The final twist is that...

> ...the town fits onto a desktop and is encased in glass. Even if he could escape, he could never live in the real world since he's very tiny.

Comment: @SJuan76 - Definitely not. I'm certain it was neither of these, nor was it The Truman Show :-)

Comment: ["The Tunnel under the world"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tunnel_under_the_World)?

Comment: @user14111 - That's the one.

Comment: user14111 beat me to it, but I was working on my answer before that comment was posted...

Comment: @Richard Seems so. I found my copy and started rereading it to make sure, but Hypnosifl saved me the trouble.

Comment: @user14111 - I've just re-read it. I'm actually quite impressed by my own description. It wasn't his *secretary* but there was a young woman involved :-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is ["The Tunnel Under the World"](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31979) by Frederik Pohl, from 1955--according to wikipedia, one of the first fictional example of [mind uploading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_uploading_in_fiction). Here's a part about the advertisers getting aggressive:

> The car took a position in the middle of the block and stood silent
>   for a few minutes. Then there was a crackle from the speaker, and a
>   giant voice chanted:
>
> "Feckle Freezers! Feckle Freezers! Gotta have a Feckle Freezer!
>   Feckle, Feckle, Feckle, Feckle, Feckle, Feckle—"
>
> It went on and on. Every house on the block had faces staring out of
>   windows by then. The voice was not merely loud; it was nearly
>   deafening.

And here's a part about discovering his house was made of metal:

> Where the old trunk had been, the cellar floor gleamed oddly bright.
>   He inspected it in the flashlight beam. It was metal!
>
> "Son of a gun," said Guy Burckhardt. He shook his head unbelievingly.
>   He peered closer, rubbed the edges of the metallic patch with his
>   thumb and acquired an annoying cut—the edges were sharp.
>
> The stained cement floor of the cellar was a thin shell. He found a
>   hammer and cracked it off in a dozen spots—everywhere was metal.
>
> The whole cellar was a copper box. Even the cement-brick walls were
>   false fronts over a metal sheath!

And his boat:

> The biggest surprise was the upside-down boat hull that blocked the
>   rear half of the cellar, relic of a brief home workshop period that
>   Burckhardt had gone through a couple of years before. From above, it
>   looked perfectly normal. Inside, though, where there should have been
>   thwarts and seats and lockers, there was a mere tangle of braces,
>   rough and unfinished.

The revelation you mentioned about the character's nature:

> He said: "Oh. The explosion in my dream."
>  
>  "It was no dream. You are right—the explosion. That was real and this
>  plant was the cause of it. The storage tanks let go and what the blast
>  didn't get, the fumes killed a little later. But almost everyone died
>  in the blast, twenty-one thousand persons. You died with them and that
>  was Dorchin's chance."
>  
>  "The damned ghoul!" said Burckhardt.
>  
>  The twisted shoulders shrugged with an odd grace. "Why? You were gone.
>  And you and all the others were what Dorchin wanted—a whole town, a
>  perfect slice of America. It's as easy to transfer a pattern from a
>  dead brain as a living one. Easier—the dead can't say no. Oh, it took
>  work and money—the town was a wreck—but it was possible to rebuild it
>  entirely, especially because it wasn't necessary to have all the
>  details exact.

And here he discovers the final twist you mention:

> Burckhardt stood paralyzed. One of the moving mountains in the
>  blinding glare came toward him.
>  
>  It towered hundreds of feet over his head; he stared up at its top,
>  squinting helplessly into the light.
>  
>  It looked like—
>  
>  Impossible!
>  
>  The voice in the loudspeaker at the door said, "Burckhardt?" But he
>  was unable to answer.
>  
>  A heavy rumbling sigh. "I see," said the voice. "You finally
>  understand. There's no place to go. You know it now. I could have told
>  you, but you might not have believed me, so it was better for you to
>  see it yourself. And after all, Burckhardt, why would I reconstruct a
>  city just the way it was before? I'm a businessman; I count costs. If
>  a thing has to be full-scale, I build it that way. But there wasn't
>  any need to in this case."
>  
>  From the mountain before him, Burckhardt helplessly saw a lesser cliff
>  descend carefully toward him. It was long and dark, and at the end of
>  it was whiteness, five-fingered whiteness....
>  
>  "Poor little Burckhardt," crooned the loudspeaker, while the echoes
>  rumbled through the enormous chasm that was only a workshop. "It must
>  have been quite a shock for you to find out you were living in a town
>  built on a table top."

Comment: Good answer (+1) but I'll bet it's not the **first** fiction about "mind uploading".

Comment: @user14111 - I smell another question a-brewing...

Comment: Well, it's the first one the wikipedians have been able to come up with--and yes, that could be another good question.

Comment: @Richard My nominee, from 1951, would be ["Izzard and the Membrane"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56104) by Walter M. Miller, Jr.

Comment: It seems as if about half of all [tag:story-identification] can be answered with "it's a Frederick Pohl story".

Comment: Now, when you say that this is "the first **fictional** example of mind uploading", what exactly are you trying to imply??

Comment: @ruakh - Just the idea that people may have written down speculations about the idea before that, but with the speculations not being part of a fictional narrative.

Comment: @SQB with the majority of the remainder being "it's a Phillip K. Dick story"?

Comment: George Orwell's 1984 was written earlier than this one, and while not the same exact mind-uploading concept, has a lot to do with false realities and altered realities.

Comment: @SQB It would be interesting to see which authors and works come up the most. I just did a search for story-identification answers mentioning Pohl, and got 44 hits, including no doubt a wrong answer or two, and a bunch where Pohl is mentioned as an editor. I get 40 hits for Dick, not all of them PK. I'd guess Heinlein and Clarke and Bradbury would do better than that.

Comment: @user14111 I think the community decided some time ago to _not_ tag answered [tag:story-identification] questions with the author. If we would've done so, this question would be a lot easier to answer.

Comment: @SQB Over at rec.arts.sf.written, at one time someone was keeping stats on most frequently requested authors and works, as well as most frequent answerers. At last count ([December 2011](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rec.arts.sf.written/yasid$20stats$20december/rec.arts.sf.written/It9zovnYWPk/i4jyxjPq_LUJ)) the most requested authors were Asimov, Anderson, Simak, Pohl, Clarke, and Brown, in that order.

Comment: This. This story is why whenever someone calls a timeloop plot 'Groundhog Day" i respond with " You mean "Tunnel Under The World" ripoff". :)

Comment: @user14111 - BTW, thanks for mentioning "Izzard and the Membrane", I finally read it and then added it to the wikipedia article as an earlier example.